# How to interact with a PaladinPanoramic API server?

Tags: javascript, .net

I am looking to read data from this API:

waconnect.paladinpanoramic.com/api/V1/Sites/

but I can't seem to get any response from the server other than `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Is there a way to interact with this API in Javascript, a web browser, or any other non-.NET client?

I am not too familiar with the .NET ecosystem, so feel free to let me know if I am missing something. Any suggestions, even high level concepts, are more than welcome.

Comment: Whether it's PHP or asp, you would use AJAX to interact with the Server Language you are using.

Comment: Lucas, please show us some code.

Comment: Panoramic Connect says the API is a web services API so you need to learn about web services. It also says "API documentation is coming soon" so you should wait for that. You do not need to wait to learn about web services in general though.

Comment: So you don't need .Net to get data from it. It uses .Net but you do not need to.

Comment: @LajosArpad Sorry, I just have that url. I think the source code is closed. I am looking to access the data for a civic technology project.

Comment: @user34660 What do you mean by "web services"? Do you mean that I should learn to send requests to an API? I have some experience doing that, but I don't know what kind of request to send. It seems that I need more info to figure that out, unless someone is familiar with this kind of API. But I wouldn't count that the "API documentation coming soon" - that site has been up for years, unchanged.

Comment: @PHPglue Are you sure I would use AJAX? According to the answer below, at this point, there doesn't seem to be enough information to tell what kind of request I should use. Perhaps you can explain how you figured that out?

Comment: If I had known you would accept what I said as an answer then I would have posted it as an answer. If I post an example of what might work then will you change the answer? Note that it is unlikely you will get it to work without documentation.

Comment: @user34660 Unless you have an answer that will successfully pull info from the api, or perhaps with a more thorough description of what is going on, then I think the current answer sums up the situation. Unfortunately my original question isn't really solvable without more documentation or source code about the API. At least that's what I've learned from this post.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this. What I have learned from your question is that it is foolish to try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the API documentation from the developer and follow that. If you navigate to http://waconnect.paladinpanoramic.com/api/V1/Sites/PContacts.ashx you indeed will get a server error that you are mentioning in your question. This is most likely because you are not providing correct parameters and/or not supposed to call it like that.

In order to find out *how* to call the API you need to contact the API publisher and request this information from them.

Comment: I will try and find the documentation for that API. Can you tell if there enough information to tell whether I should send an HTTP, AJAX, and/or XHR request?

Comment: It can be anything at this stage.